# How does this question have the same tag twice?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tagging, editing

[This question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/how-does-the-outrider-work-in-agricola) shows as having [rules](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules), [agricola](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agricola), and [rules](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules).  When I tried to edit the question to remove one of the duplicates, it only showed one instance of the duplicate.  Why is the question showing the tag twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting defect.

I cleared it by removing [rules](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules) as we're [discouraging it's use](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/911/40).

Comment: Has anything ever been synonimized with rules?  I wondered if perhaps these were two different tags when the question was created.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - That is probably what happened, I believe I've seen it before with other tags.

Comment: @MonicaCellio That's what probably happened; it was in the early days of the tag synonym feature.

Comment: The rules tag - so good I used it twice! ;-)