# Merge teaching and learning?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[learning](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) has 11 questions and the following wiki excerpt:

> How to gain skill in a particular game, or teach others how to learn a game

[teaching](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) has 9 questions and no wiki.

What is the difference between these?  Can we merge them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They've both been nominated for deletion in [this question](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/911/1749). However, I think this [main site question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/8891/1749) may have been created to try to demonstrate [teaching](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching)'s worth, so there might not yet be consensus on their fate.

If they're not eliminated entirely, I agree that they should be merged.

Comment: I see some good questions there, though the other meta post makes a good point about "meta" tags.  Merge now and discuss elimination later?  At the very least we shouldn't have *two* of these running around.

Comment: Sounds good to me. I think [tag:teaching] should be the one to keep, if any.

Comment: I agree with shujaa -- teaching is more descriptive and self-evident than learning, in my opinion.

Comment: I've merged these: [tag:learning] -> [tag:teaching].