# Do we really need a rules tag, again?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

From what I can tell, we determined that the [rules](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules) tag was a meta tag and not useful for the site back in 2012: [Do we really need a rules tag?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/818/do-we-really-need-a-rules-tag). Well, it's back. It appears to have been recreated back in September 2022 with [this post](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/posts/57954/revisions) and added to fifteen total questions in the last few months.

Reading through the answers given to the original thread back in 2012, the reasons given for not using the tag (that were well supported by the community then) seem to apply just the same now almost eleven years later. So while I am open to contrary feedback, I am making this a [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) since burning the tag will not leave any of the fifteen questions untagged.

Comment: I've added a [status-review] tag to this, so that it'll end up in the staff's queue; they have the tools to blacklist tags.

Comment: It seems like we should be removing it from the existing questions (especially as it got recently  added to some) while we wait on other possible action.

Comment: @JoeW: Indeed – for tag-block requests, we ask that the community remove the problematic tag from the questions it's currently on first (unless it's on too many questions for the community to handle on its own, e.g. 75-100 or more) before escalating the request to staff. (Since it's only on 15 questions right now, hopefully y'all should be able to get that done pretty quickly.)

Comment: @V2Blast I have gone ahead and removed the tag from those 15 questions so we are good on that front.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[status-completed](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Tag was already *burninated*, and now is *banninated*

[image]

**FYI**: This was added via what we call an [***Intrinsic Block***](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60425/209031), in that the concept of `rules` is intrinsic to just about every question on board and card games, that it should almost be considered a de-facto tag on every question, so no need to explicitly add to each.

Answer (score 9):

[tag-block-request](/questions/tagged/tag-block-request)

The [rules](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules) tag should be burninated, and it should also be blocked from usage. Our situation is [just like that of RPG.SE's](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4932/1204): the tag isn't useful because it applies to over 90% of our questions, and thus essentially becomes a tag tax. Also just like RPG.SE, it keeps coming back, because people keep asking questions about rules, so we should go ahead and block it to keep it gone.

Answer (score 5):

### Heck... No!

We had the discussion like a felt half dozen times. None of the arguments has changed: when is a question **not** about rules? Almost never. It serves no purpose!